# Как грамотно убрать фокус с TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброе утро. Как грамотно убрать фокус с TextBox? Свойство *Focused* для данного контрола доступно только для чтения. Как вариант устанавливаю фокус на label, но на сколько это правильно - не знаю.

Comment: `TextBox1.TabStop = False;` ?

Comment: Нет, это не проходит. Фокус остается на контроле.

Comment: тут необходимо себе уяснить, что просто "снять" фокус - нельзя. Фокус где-то должен быть. Не знаю является ли установка фокуса на label - лучшим местом для фокуса, это вам решать. А `TextBox1.TabStop = False;` просто делает контрол "нефокусабельным"

Comment: Не понимаю, что даст изменение этого свойства. Визуально все тоже самое. Проблему это не решает. Фокус стоит в текстбоксе... После нажатия на кнопку нужно его убрать. Фокусабельный или нет - фокус как был в контроле так и остался.

Comment: вы не так поняли

Comment: свойство TabStop указывает можно ли установить фокус на данный контрол или нет. После ввода значения в текстбоксе мне нужно убрать фокус. Я не понял первый комментарий. Ответ не в ту сторону.

Comment: вообще для понимания тут нужны детали UX/UI, иногда после ввода текста в поле правильнее переводить фокус на кнопку ОК, например, и тп

Comment: Это обычный поисковик на главной форме.

Comment: ну так может лучше будет переводить фокус на кнопку "искать", если она есть, или на результаты поиска

Comment: да, такая кнопка есть. Как вариант, так и сделаю.

Comment: Возвращаясь к нашей беседе, прежде чем беспокоить сообщество подобным вопросом, а почему бы сначала самому не разобраться, в том, что такое вообще фокус? Я не буду ставить минус, но большинство вопросов именно такие. На этом я намерен закончить нашу дискуссию.

Comment: Спасибо за коммент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Focused** - свойство, возвращающее находится ли сейчас элемент в фокусе.

Для того чтобы сфокусироваться на элементе, можно использовать `winapi` функцию `SetFocus`.

Пример кода:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static void SetFocus(IntPtr Handle);

void OnClick(object sender) {
    if((Button)sender.Name == "Button")) {
        SetFocus((Button)sender.Handle);
    }
}
```

Или можно установить хук на WndProc, но скорее всего вам это нужно.

Подробнее о хуке WndProc на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: он просил снять фокус

Comment: @Sublihim, что мешает SetFocus(Window.Handle)?

Comment: Мда, downvote без объяснения причин, когда был дан четкий ответ.

Comment: Ответ, вроде, был другим.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы убрать фокус, [нужно передать в SetFocus параметр NULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646312(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **hWnd [in, optional]**
>
> A handle to the window that will receive the keyboard input. If this parameter is NULL, keystrokes are ignored.

Код:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private extern static IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

// ...

SetFocus(IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Это отрабатывает.

Comment: а чем это лучше перевода фокуса на другой контрол?

Comment: @Anatol SetFocus посылает сообщение WM_KILLFOCUS на исходный контрол и WM_SETFOCUS на новый. Если указать NULL, то второе сообщение не отправляется. Конечно, это вряд ли серьезно улучшит производительность.

Comment: А если кнопок много, и каждому нужно убрать фокус, как быть?